# Find generating function for the following conditions $a_n=$ $(-2)^{2n-1}$ for $n\geq2$, $a_0=0$, $a_1=10$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

$a_n=$ $(-2)^{2n-1}$ for $n\geq2$, $a_0=0$, $a_1=10$

Solution I found:

$A(z)=0*z^0+10*z^1+\sum_{n=\geq2}^{\infty}(-2)^{2n-1}*z^n=$

$$A(z)=10 + (-2)^3z^2+(-2)^5z^3+...+(-2)^{2n-1}z^n$$

$$(-2)^{2n-1}z^n=b_n$$

$$\frac{b^{n+1}}{b^n}$$

$$\frac{(-2)^{2(n+1)-1}z^{n+1}}{(-2)^{2n-1}z^{n}}=(-2)^2z$$

$$q=4z$$
$$W_0=(-2)^3z^2$$
$$A(z)=10z+\frac{(-2)^3z^2}{1-4z}$$

Is this solved correctly? If so, could anyone explain $W_0$ part?
I think its something connected to conditions at the start.

Is this the right answer?

Answer (score 1):

Using the sum of a geometric series,
$$
\begin{align}
10x+\sum_{k=2}^\infty(-2)^{2n-1}x^n
&=10x-\frac12\sum_{k=2}^\infty(4x)^n\\
&=10x-\frac{8x^2}{1-4x}\tag1
\end{align}
$$
which agrees with your answer.

The sum of an infinite geometric series with first term $a$ and common ratio $r$ (with $|r|\lt1$) is
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty ar^n=\frac{a}{1-r}\tag2
$$
The $W_0$ part of your answer is just the first term: $a$ in $(2)$.